# Rails creating multiple entries at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out the cleanest way to create multiple DB entries at once (or if it's even a good idea).

I have an Event model, which has many Bands and many Venues, through the event_bands and event_venues models.

Right now, the user first creates the event, then is redirected to the form to create the event_band and event_venue relationships. I would like to streamline all of this into one form if possible, like this (bottom lines are most relevant):

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
  <%= f.label :contact %>
  <%= f.text_field :contact %><br />
  <%= f.label :price %>
  <%= f.text_field :price %><br />
  <%= f.label :info %>
  <%= f.text_area :info %><br />
  <%= f.label :date %>
  <%= f.date_select :date, start_year: 2014 %><br />
  <%= f.label :time %>
  <%= f.text_field :time, placeholder: "7:40pm" %><br />

  <%= f.label :band %>
  <%= select(:event_band, :band_id, options_for_select(Band.order(name: :asc).collect { |b| [b.name, b.id]} )) %><br />
  <%= f.label :venue %>
  <%= select(:event_venue, :venue_id, options_for_select(Venue.order(name: :asc).collect { |v| [v.name, v.id]} )) %><br />

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Because the `event_band` and `event_model` require `event.id`, I guess I would have to use an `after_create` callback to build and save them. The issue I'm having conceptualizing this is that I want to post those extra `:band_id` and `:venue_id` params through the form for the event.

Is there a cleaner way to handle posting params for multiple models through one form and then using them in a callback or am I headed in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fields_for : [see doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)